# Displaying data out of foreach statements

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to figure out the best way to output data outside of a foreach while still maintaining all the results.

The variables I am trying to get are `$pending_friend_1` and `$pending_friend_img`.

Currently, I am accomplishing this with the one variable `$pending_friend_1` by setting it to an array `$friends_pending_arr[] = $pending_friend_1;` and then imploding it outside of the `foreach` loop. However, I cannot figure out how to do it with two different variables while outputting it into the `$pending_friend_list`.

Is there a better way to do this than what I am or can I do it with the `implode` method and if so, how can I do it with both variables? I am wanting both variables within `<div class="pending_friend_user">`.

```
$pending_friend_list = null;
$pending_friend_images = null;
foreach ($pending_friend_rows as $pending_friend_row) {
    $pending_friend_1           = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
    $pending_friend_2           = $pending_friend_row['friend_two'];
    $pending_friend_status      = $pending_friend_row['status'];
    $pending_friend_status_date = $pending_friend_row['date'];
    $pending_friend_img         = $pending_friend_row['img'];
    $total_pending_friends      = $pending_friend_1 . "<br>" . $pending_friend_2;

    if ($pending_friend_2 == $user_id) {
        $pending_friend_list_approve = '<img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" class="pending_approve_friend" alt="Approve Friend">';
        $pending_friend_list_decline = '<img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" class="pending_decline_friend" alt="Approve Friend">';
        $friends_pending_arr[] = $pending_friend_1;
        $friends_pending_img_arr[] = $pending_friend_img;
        $pending_friend_list = '<div class="pending-friend-list-row"><div class="pending_friend_user">'. implode
            ('</div><div class="pending_friend_list_decision"><div class="total-center">' . $pending_friend_list_approve . $pending_friend_list_decline . 
            '</div></div></div><div class="pending-friend-list-row"><div class="pending_friend_user">', $friends_pending_arr) .
            '</div><div class="pending_friend_list_decision"><div class="total-center">' . $pending_friend_list_approve . $pending_friend_list_decline . '</div></div></div>';
    }
```

Example:

```
$pending_friend_list = null;
$pending_friend_images_output = "";
$friends_pending_output = "";
forloop {
    $pending_friend_1           = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
    $pending_friend_2           = $pending_friend_row['friend_two'];
    $pending_friend_status      = $pending_friend_row['status'];
    $pending_friend_status_date = $pending_friend_row['date'];
    $pending_friend_img         = $pending_friend_row['img'];
$friends_pending_output .= $pending_friend_1;
$pending_friend_images_output .= '<img src="' . $pending_friend_img .'">';
}
$pending_friend_list = 
    '<div class="pending-friend-list-row"><div class="pending_friend_user"><div class="pending_friend_list_img"> ' . echo $pending_friend_images_output . '</div>
    </div><div class="pending_friend_list_decision"><div class="total-center">' . $pending_friend_list_approve . $pending_friend_list_decline . 
    '</div></div></div>;
```

Desired HTML:

```
 <div id="pending-friend-list-dropdown">
    <div id="pending-friend-list-container">
        <div id="pending-friend-list-summary">
            <div class="pending-friend-list-row">
                <div class="pending_friend_user">
                    <div class="pending_friend_list_img">
                        <img src=friend1>
                    </div>  
                    <div> user_id //friend 1// </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pending_friend_list_decision">
                    <div class="total-center">
                        <img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" class="pending_approve_friend" alt="Approve Friend">
                        <img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" class="pending_decline_friend" alt="Decline Friend">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pending-friend-list-row">
                <div class="pending_friend_user">
                    <div class="pending_friend_list_img">
                        <img src=friend1>
                    </div>  
                    <div> user_id //friend 2// </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pending_friend_list_decision">
                    <div class="total-center">
                        <img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" class="pending_approve_friend" alt="Approve Friend">
                        <img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" class="pending_decline_friend" alt="Decline Friend">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pending-friend-list-row">
                <div class="pending_friend_user">
                    <div class="pending_friend_list_img">
                        <img src=friend1>
                    </div>  
                    <div> user_id //friend 3// </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pending_friend_list_decision">
                    <div class="total-center">
                        <img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" class="pending_approve_friend" alt="Approve Friend">
                        <img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" class="pending_decline_friend" alt="Decline Friend">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My updated full code:

```
$pending_list_output = 
    '<div id="pending-friend-list-dropdown">
        <div id="pending-friend-list-container">
            <div id="pending-friend-list-summary">
                <div class="pending_friend_list_content"><?php echo $total_pending_count; ?></div>';

//Display pending friends
//$pending_friend_list = null;
    $status_pending = '1';
    $friends_pending_sql = "
        SELECT f.*, p.*,coalesce(p.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') as img
        FROM friends f LEFT JOIN
             profile_img p 
             ON p.user_id = f.friend_one 
        WHERE f.friend_two = ? AND f.status = ? AND
              p.id = (select max(p2.id) from profile_img p2 where p2.user_id = p.user_id)
    ";
    $pending_friend_count_stmt = $con->prepare($friends_pending_sql);
    $pending_friend_count_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $status_pending));
    $pending_friend_rows = $pending_friend_count_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $pending_friend_list_approve = '<img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" class="pending_approve_friend" alt="Approve Friend">';
    $pending_friend_list_decline = '<img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" class="pending_decline_friend" alt="Decline Friend">';
    foreach ($pending_friend_rows as $pending_friend_row) {
        $pending_friend_1               = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
        $pending_friend_2               = $pending_friend_row['friend_two'];
        $pending_friend_status          = $pending_friend_row['status'];
        $pending_friend_status_date     = $pending_friend_row['date'];
        $pending_friend_img             = $pending_friend_row['img'];
        $total_pending_friends          = $pending_friend_1 . "<br>" . $pending_friend_2;
        //$friends_pending_output       .= $pending_friend_1;
        $pending_friend_images_output   = '<img src="' . $pending_friend_img .'">';

        if ($pending_friend_2 == $user_id) {
            $pending_friend_list_approve;
            $pending_friend_list_decline;
            $pending_list_output .= 
                '<div class="pending-friend-list-row">
                    <div class="pending_friend_user">
                        <div class="pending_friend_list_img"> ' . $pending_friend_images_output . '</div>
                        <div class="pending_friend_list_username">' . $pending_friend_1 . '</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pending_friend_list_decision">
                        <div class="total-center">' . $pending_friend_list_approve . $pending_friend_list_decline . '</div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
        }
        else {
            $pending_list_output = "No pending friends at this time.";
        }
    }
    if ($total_pending_count == 0) {
        $total_pending_count = "No new requests.";
    }
    else {
        $total_pending_count = "Pending Friends - " . $total_pending_count;
    }
    $pending_list_output .= 
            '</div>
        </div>  
    </div>';
    echo $pending_list_output;
 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: just to clarify, is the if statement inside the foreach or outside?

Comment: ok, then is it you print the $pending_friend_list outside the foreach? (this is your question?

Comment: if you simply want to capture the variable outside the foreach, set a variable `$x = ''; ` and `$y = '';` before the foreach and then assign `$x = $pending_friend_1` and `$y = $pending_friend_img;` within the foreach. then you can print these outside your foreach. Is this what you are looking for or do you want to maintain the relationship of img and friend?

Comment: your $x and $y variables will get reassigned for each iteration, so you can do $x = $x.','.$pending_friend_1 if you wish to concatenate a csv list instead of putting them in an array.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `implode()` every time through the loop. You should push onto the array during the loop, and call `implode` after the loop to join them all together. Otherwise, each time through the loop you're joining subsets of the array.

Comment: `foreach () { $array[] = something; } $combined = implode('separator', $array);`

Comment: Why do you assign `$pending_friend_list_approve` and `$pending_friend_list_decline` each time through the loop? It doesn't contain anything from `$pending_friend_row`.

Comment: @Barmar So the approve and decline output on each row/record. So if there are 4 pending friends, each pending friend has an approve/decline option.

Comment: But the approve and decline output is the same every time. I understand why you're concatenating it each time, but why do you need to reassign the variables, instead of just setting them once before the loop?

Comment: @Barmar I am defining the approve and decline within the for loop in the if statement. How could I do it before the loop. I still don't get what is wrong the approve/decline in my output. I was just shown this type of example for outputting out of the foreach, so I am definitely open to the best way to do this.

Comment: Just move those two assignments before the `foreach`. They don't use any variables, so they don't need to be inside the loop. Anyway, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I moved them out of the `foreach`, then just called the variables in the if statement, within the `foreach`. I don't get the implode part though for my case.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `implode()`. That's for putting something **between** the elements of an array. But if you want something to be before or after **every** element, you'll be missing one of them.

Comment: Just concatenate to a variable each time through the loop. Start with `$output = "";` before the loop, and in the loop do `$output .= things to add to it;`. Then when the loop is done you can `echo $output;`

Comment: @Barmar I made an edit to my question with an example based on your suggestion. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: You don't put `. echo $variable` inside a variable assignment, just `. $variable`

Comment: It would help if you showed what you want the resulting HTML to look like. If you did that, you'd probably be able to figure this out yourself. Because I'm totally confused about how you want to group all the information. In your updated script, you're putting the images separate from the names. And you just have one approve and decline icon at the end of everything, not after each friend.

Comment: @Barmar I just added an image of what this looks like with my original code. I am wanting it to look like that, but if there were more pending friends, it would show more containers with the pending friend pic, id, accept and decline. I am currently working on my code to what I posted a bit ago.

Comment: Show what you want the HTML to look like, and with multiple friends. I can't tell the HTML structure from a screen shot, and I can't tell how you want to combine multiple friends when you only show one.

Comment: What part of that output is `$pending_friend_1`? I assumed that was the friend name, but all you show is the image, not the name. What's `55`?

Comment: @Barmar I added the desired HTML w/ multiple friends and my new updated code based on my take on your suggestion. .......... Looking at my new updated code, it looks like I left `$pending_friend_1` out. That was previously initiated with the implode. So, I will have to add it back. 55 is the user_id. I still need to add a `JOIN` to my query to match the user_id to my `users` table to get the username. Just trying to get this to work first.

Comment: Just made a quick edit to the HTML example. I accidentally wrapped the image div around the user_id part. I took the user_id out to be a sibbling to the img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your HTML structure directly into the strings, and concatenate the variables where they need to be inserted.

```
$output = '<div id="pending-friend-list-dropdown">
                <div id="pending-friend-list-container">
                    <div id="pending-friend-list-summary">';
foreach ($pending_friend_rows as $pending_friend_row) {
    $pending_friend_1           = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
    $pending_friend_img         = $pending_friend_row['img'];
    $output .= '<div class="pending-friend-list-row">
                    <div class="pending_friend_user">
                        <div class="pending_friend_list_img">
                            <img src="' . $pending_friend_img . '">
                        </div>  
                        <div>' . $pending_friend_1 . '</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pending_friend_list_decision">
                        <div class="total-center">
                            <img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" class="pending_approve_friend" alt="Approve Friend">
                            <img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" class="pending_decline_friend" alt="Decline Friend">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
}
$output .= '</div>
        </div>
    </div>';

echo $output;
```

Comment: I am trying to get this to work. Why would `$output` start with `'<div id="pending-friend-list-dropdown">
                <div id="pending-friend-list-container">
                    <div id="pending-friend-list-summary">';` ? There is only one of all of this.

Comment: That's outside the loop, so it's only done once. That's used to create the beginning of the DIV, which the rows are then appended to.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I did it just as you wrote it. Just changed the output variable name. The approve/decline is not in the correct position and only one user_id is displaying and that out of position too.. I updated my question with new code and pic.

Comment: You can't put `<?php echo $total_pending_count; ?>` inside a string. You need to do concatenation with `.`

Comment: Noticed that a second ago and changed it. Still doesn't resolve why the formatting is so messed up. When I was re-positioning the `$total_pending_count` I noticed that both of the `user_id`'s were there, just the first one is being covered by the second image. Why would the format be so messed up?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your CSS?

Comment: Check the DOM in Developer Tools, make sure everything is grouped properly. Maybe there's a missing `</div>` somewhere.

Comment: It was such a simple over-look. I had to do the `inline-block` html fix. Doing this `</div><div class="pending_friend_list_decision">` So there wasn't any html space in between the two elements. I appreciate you working with me through this! I learned a lot.